# Why do my Google Analytics and CloudFlare analytics results differ?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, cloudflare

Here are my stats for January 28th with CloudFlare:

[image]

And here are my stats for January 28th with Google Analytics:

[image]

Why might my statistical results be different between Google Analytics and CloudFlare's analytics?

On one side, Google Analytics is very reputable and been there for years. On the other side, CloudFlare is a CDN, thus your site's content is distributed around their servers around the globe, so they claim that their analytics are more accurate than other services (implying GA) who rely on JavaScript.

**Note: Google Analytics is installed on pages automatically by Cloudflare. They inject it on all pages even 404 pages.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Analytics is based on JavaScript running on the client whereas CloudFlare's numbers are based on how many requests they get for each resource.

Analytics is more likely to be showing legitimate users running full browsers, whereas CloudFlare's requests could be coming from bots or other sources

Comment: I would also add that people have an option to opt out of Google Analytics, and not for cloudflare.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given is correct. If you want a more detailed explanation about why CloudFlare and Google Analytics would different, then please read [this](https://blog.cloudflare.com/understanding-analytics-when-is-a-page-view-n/).

Answer (score 0):

As CloudFlare's analytics come from the backend, they include every request for an image, favicon, CSS, etc. and confusingly calls it "page views". Google's analytics shows page views as the user would see and read them, a whole page containing images, html, css etc. and calls them "page views" as well.

Comment: That's inaccurate. Cloudflare includes "hits" for every item which got requested as opposed to "pageviews". The number of hits I have is 1,000,000 daily.

Comment: That's what I meant, but I'll tidy the answer up if you find it unclear.

Comment: Got it, But what you said is irrelevant to the question,  we are comparing page-views and not hits.

Comment: Now I'm confused too. I just meant to point out CloudFlare is using an inaccurate word to describe what they're actually counting; files requested.

Comment: That's not true.

Comment: The [link](https://blog.cloudflare.com/understanding-analytics-when-is-a-page-view-n/) in Damon's answer above is from the source (this answer can be edited to correspond to that as a further explanation).